# Processor pipeline state preservation

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, x86-64, cpu-architecture

Is there any situation where the state of the processor pipeline (with already decoded or prefetched instructions) is saved and subsequently reloaded after resumption during a thread sleep/ context switch / interrupt etc.? (May be as a optimization).

Comment: Are you prepared to count code-translating VLIW microarchitecures like Transmeta/Denver that (to a first-order approximation) pretty much _work_ that way? :P

Comment: That was good to know :). But I was mostly focusing on x86_64 and ARM architectures.

Comment: Transmeta's crusoe design *is* an x86 CPU.  Internally, it's implemented by JIT-compiling x86 machine code to VLIW machine code, and caching that.  So it finds the parallelism once, and doesn't have to do it on the fly every time the x86 architectural state passes over the same code.  This is what @Notlikethat was getting at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible for any CPU I'm aware of.  There's no interface for doing it, and no conditions under which a CPU does it on its own.  Dumping a huge amount of internal CPU state to RAM would take more cycles than it would save.  Having the OS keep track of the variable-size chunks of RAM needed for this would just make the overhead worse.

If anything was worth saving, BTW, it would be results of already executed instruction that can't retire yet, because of a load that missed in cache.  (All the common out-of-order execution designs for mainstream ISAs use in-order retirement to support precise exceptions.  Out-of-order retirement with checkpointing / rollback on exceptions and mispredicts has been proposed.  Search kilo-instruction processor, IIRC.)

---

(flawed idea): An aggressive out-of-order design could avoid wasting too much work on context switches by delaying the write of the interrupt-return address when an external interrupt arrives.  i.e. they could pretend that the interrupt came in later than it did by allowing some instructions already in the pipeline to keep executing.  If the user-space instruction pointer isn't needed until the interrupt handler returns, the CPU could clearing the pipeline.

Hrm, this has the major difficulty that register values on entry into the interrupt handler also depends on the architectural state, so this probably can't work.

This def. can't work for interrupts generated by user-space, because that fixes the return address.

This isn't an issue for threads that put themselves to sleep while waiting on a spinlock with `monitor / mwait` or something.  `mwait` presumably doesn't take effect until it retires, and it won't retire until all previous work has been done.  It would defeat the intended purpose for the CPU to be aggressive about speculatively executing past `mwait`, I think.  Or maybe `mwait` doesn't even flush the pipeline, and just saves power.

Comment: I am going to accept this as the correct answer since you make a good case for this being not so in the general case.

Comment: @chamibuddhika: If you're aware of *any* specific case where anything like this is done, I'd like to hear about it.  AFAIK, any optimizations to minimize the throwing away of useful data are done entirely within the CPU, with no software control or visible architectural state.  One case I can think of where something like this is done is with data-caches being tagged by VM context, so switching between hypervisor and guest(s) doesn't have to invalidate the caches.  Actually, this may involve software detecting the feature and not running a cache-invalidate instruction.  google the details...

Comment: No not really that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

The idea has been proposed, but you'd need a much denser memory technology which is only now becoming available. See this paper for example:

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6489970

Basically, they propose pipes composed of a new set of latches & registers based on memristors (resistive non-volatile memory components), that can hold multiple values corresponding to multiple threads. Control logic can then tell all latches which thread should be active, and allow simultaneous context switching throughout the entire pipe.

Keep in mind that this only enhances the granularity to the latch level. Modern CPUs with simultaneous multithreading can already have different threads active on different units level without context switches, simple through arbitration. Other units with inherent parallelism may already handle multiple threads per cycle (e.g. - multi-ported ALUs)